# How to configure a thread that execute on a given time

Tags: java, algorithm, scheduler

I am making a meeting broadcast application which will broadcast the message to the participant of meeting.
There is a meeting data checker thread which execute after 5 minute.
I have done this using this code :

```
 ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
 scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new DataAccessSchedule(), 0, 5,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Now the in DataAccessScedule the query get the data of meeting which are expected to be started after 15  minutes,so I get the data before 15 minutes and the time in table are: 01:45 ,... 01:50 , ... 01:52 ,..

so i have calculated the time of all in millisecond by taking difference from current time so now the time in milis are x,y and z.
I want to fire the thread on x , y and z time and these thread destroy itself after execution.I do not want to run scheduler here like above did using Executors.
Please tell me how should i do that ?

Comment: I am using this code to invoke threads:
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
      executorService.schedule(new MeetingBroadcaster(),InvokingTimeInSec,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

It is in a loop which could run 1 to n times depend on meeting count so I have two question here 

1.If a object is created again & again will it destroy the prior objects(threads) because its reference will be replace by new object reference.
2.If it execute successfullt will the thread destroy itself ?

Comment: If you can't pass in the exact clock-time to execute at, you can always calculate the difference between the schedule time and the time now, then pass in the difference as minutes or seconds. Not ideal, but it would work. Btw, do you have an API documentation for ScheduledExecutorService? You need to mention such details in your questions as not everyone here would be familiar with the APIs you use in your application.

Comment: Here it is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: Yea, if you want to use `ScheduledExecutorService`, you'll have to do what I said. You can keep your code clean by creating a static method that will take in a clock-time (with or without date, depending on your application) and return you the difference between it and the time now (in minutes or seconds, depending on your application). The difference can easily be used to construct your `ScheduledExecutorService` instance. The static method can be reused any number of times wherever you need it.

Comment: Or if you need it in a lot of places, you could simply extend `ScheduledExecutorService` and add the functionality in your custom extension class.

Answer (score 0):

You need a scheduler library for that, for example [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), that supports **cron** expressions to specify exactly when the task should be launched.

You can also configure it to run the task finite number of times.

An alternative for writing sheduler library would be to write the similar functionality yourself. You'll need one task running periodically, with the precision you require (it could be 1 minute, but also 1 second) and checking all entries in the data structure, if their start condition matches current date (for example, by matching the date/time against **cron** expression). It would be, however, reinventing the wheel so don't do as long if you don't want some extra funktionality the existing libraries doesn't provide.

Comment: Why? You want to write everything yourself?

Comment: I want to do it using ScheduledExecutorService

Comment: I am using this code to invoke threads: ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); executorService.schedule(new MeetingBroadcaster(),InvokingTimeInSec,TimeUnit.SECONDS); It is in a loop which could run 1 to n times depend on meeting count so I have two question here 1.If a object is created again & again will it destroy the prior objects(threads) because its reference will be replace by new object reference. 2.If it execute successfully will the thread destroy itself ?